# Error : Wrong comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, warnings

My code seems fine, but I get this warning (warning: comparison between pointer and integer), what is the best solution to solve this problem?
I have already used double notation marks for (`char exit = "E"`), also used the same thing with while but the same problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c[1];
    char exit = 'E';

    while (c != exit)
    {
        printf("Enter a character\n\n");
        scanf("%s", c);
        printf("your character is : %s\n-------------------\n", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: `c` is an (uninitialized) array, `exit` is a char. You can't compare them directly.

Comment: `scanf("%s", c);` just begs for a buffer overflow.

Comment: thanks a lot it works @pmg ,,but when i type E the program does not out from while loop and ending the the program,, it still looping

Comment: Your `c` array has enough space for `1` character. Strings include a `'\0'` making your `c` array capable of holding empty strings only.

Comment: Okay!! but what should i do? I did not get you clearly @pmg

Comment: If you're not going to treat `c` as a string (no reason why you should) see @bbcbbc1 answer below.

Comment: it works and you programmed what i need thanks @pmg,, the program takes Enter press as a character too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i believe this is what you are trying to do.

warning is because you have not initialzed your character and also you were  comparing address of character to character value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c[1];
    char exit = 'E';

    while ((c[0]=getchar()) != exit)
    {
        if(c[0]==EOF)break;
        printf("your character is : %c\n",c[0]) ;
    }
    printf("ended");
}
```

Comment: No need for `c` to be an array then.

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int` and you'd want to check that the character is not `EOF`

Comment: the value `EOF` is an integer, usually with a value of -1.  A integer is more than 1 character (typically 4 characters) so, depending on if a `char` is signed or unsigned on your system, the comparison with EOF may (or may not) work

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main()
> {
>     char c[1];
>     char exit = 'E';
>
>     while (c != exit)  // here ...
>     {
>         printf("Enter a character\n\n");
>         scanf("%s", c);
>         printf("your character is : %s\n-------------------\n", c);
>     }
> }
> ```

you are trying to compare a `char` to the pointer the array `c` decays to. What you perhaps wanted to do is to compare the first character of the array to the character `exit`:

```
while (c[0] != exit)
```

But that still doesn't make much sense since `c` is uninitialized and the user not yet had a chance to make any input. Better use a `do ... while`-loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c[1];
    char exit = 'E';

    do {
        printf("Enter a character\n\n");
        scanf("%s", c);
        printf("your character is : %s\n-------------------\n", c);
    } while (c[0] != exit);
}
```

Next thing is, that `scanf("%s", c);` could fail (yes unlikely, but possible). And the user could enter more characters than there is room for in the array `c`. You should never use `scanf()` whithout checking the return value nor `"%s"` without specifying a `WIDTH` for the conversion specifier to limit the characters put into the array.

When reading a string you need memory for `WIDTH` characters + a terminating `'\0'`. So if you want to read a string of one character, the array has to have at least 2 elements:

```
#include <stdlib.h
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c[2];
    char exit = 'E';

    do {
        printf("Enter a character\n\n");
        while (scanf("%1s", c) != 1 ) {
            fputs("Input error!\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        printf("your character is : %s\n-------------------\n", c);
    } while (c[0] != exit);
}
```

But if you only want to read one character you are better off with `getchar()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
{
    int ch;
    while (printf("Enter a character\n\n"),
           (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != 'E')
    {
        printf("your character is: %c\n-------------------\n", (char) ch);
    }    
}
```

Comment: There is not much point in using `%1s` when all that is needed is one non-space character